# Downloading OpenStreetMap data with street names and city attributes for ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap

I'm currently trying to download data from OpenStreetMap specifically from San Carlos, Venezuela. I'd like to take the OSM file and convert it to SHP for use in ArcGIS.

I've used geofabrik for other country's in the past, but Venezuela is not available for download. Exporting a bounding box of the city directly from OpenStreetMap, then using OpenStreetMap Toolbox to convert the OSM to SHP gives me the lines but it's missing street names and city. Ideally I'd have addresses as well, but I can live with just street names.

Is there any way to achieve this? Export all streets within a city from OpenStreetMap, then convert it to SHP with city and street name attributes?

Comment: Have you read http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles#Create_your_own_shapefiles and do those solutions not work?

Answer (score 2):

To do this I would use the tools of [ArcGIS Editor for OpenStreetMap](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/openstreetmap) to download a file geodatabase in your area of interest.

> OSM Editor makes it easy for you to download OSM data, use it for
>   analysis in your research and maps, and upload changes back to the OSM
>   database if desired.

If you prefer shapefiles over the feature classes that it creates then they are easily converted.